# Unable To Login Via Default Login Credentials of Admin in Ambari

Tags: hadoop, docker, ambari, hortonworks-sandbox

I installed *hortonworks sandbox* around two weeks ago on a cloud server of linode with a machine of **8GB RAM**. I access this node of **Linode** via **Putty**.

Everything is working fine. Also, I am able to login ***Ambari*** via the default login credentials like `maria_dev`, `raj_ops`, `holger_gov` and `amy_ds`.

But I am unable to login via the default login credentials of admin. I think that I've forgotten the password. Since I am really new to this framework, I am unable to recover the password. In the command line, I tried the following commands :

```
ambari-server restart  
ambari-admin-password-reset
```

But each time, I am getting the `command not found` error.

Can someone please help me to recover the password ? or help me to login via the login credentials of admin ?

Comment: Are you sure `admin` user exists in the Hortonworks sandbox? Your command can't be found if you are not in the Docker container of the Ambari server

Comment: Yes, the admin user exists. I tried changing the password in the Docker container. But the effort was futile. :(

Comment: You can change passwords in the Mysql/Postgres database behind Ambari

Comment: How can I access that database ? Can you please guide me for commands ?

Comment: In `/var/lib/ambari-server`... There is a config file for the Ambari database. If it is postgres, then you can see this https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/155726/unable-to-login-via-default-login-credentials-of-a.html

Answer (score 0):

If you get the "command not found error" on `ambari-server restart` command, then probably you are logged into a wrong cluster node. Ambari-server is installed to a single host of a cluster.

Comment: So how can I log into the right cluster node ? and how to find out this right cluster node ? i was running the command of ambari-server restart after running this command :  docker exec -it sandbox-hdp bash

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

Ambari server failing, Check if Ambari server is running or not by following command

```
ps -aux | grep ambari
```

If you can not find ambari server process, please check a log for ambari-server. You can find ambari-server logs at `/var/log/ambari-server/ambari-server.log`

Ambari-server is Running but its missing from `PATH` please check if ambari-server is actually running ?

```
[root@sandbox ~]# ps aux | grep ambari-server

    root         9  0.0  0.0  11356  1288 ?        S+   12:24   0:00 /bin/sh -c ambari-server start 1>/var/log/startup_script.log 2> "temp  Ambari server.log" || touch temp.errors;
    root        15  0.0  0.0  11360  1388 ?        S+   12:24   0:00 bash /usr/sbin/ambari-server start
    root        46  0.8  0.3 116772 15168 ?        D+   12:24   0:01 /usr/bin/python /usr/sbin/ambari-server.py start
    root      2324  0.0  0.0   8024   844 pts/0    R+   12:26   0:00 grep ambari-server
```

**Solution 2:**

Try to find out where Ambari is Installed.

```
find / -name "ambari-server"
```

Try running ambari-server --help with full path. It will print following message as below.

```
[root@sandbox ~]# /usr/sbin/ambari-server --help
Using python  /usr/bin/python
Usage: /usr/sbin/ambari-server
        {start|stop|restart|setup|setup-jce|upgrade|status|upgradestack|setup-ldap|sync-ldap|set-current|setup-security|setup-sso|refresh-stack-hash|backup|restore|update-host-names|enable-stack|check-database|db-cleanup} [options]
        Use /usr/sbin/ambari-server.py <action> --help to get details on options available.
        Or, simply invoke ambari-server.py --help to print the options.
```

In case `/usr/sbin/` missing from path then you have to manually add PATH with `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin`